# Custom bean resolver for constructor parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Is it possible to provide a custom bean resolver to spring?
I have a constructor

```
Person(@myCustomAnnotation name : String)
```

I want to be able to put a different value for name based on if the annotation is there or not.

Comment: add the tag of the language you use

Answer (score 0):

I think the `@Value` annotation is what you're looking for. Person will have to be a managed bean though.

```
@Bean("jim")
fun getJim(@Value("\${person.name:Jim Jones}") name : String) = Person(name)
```